# Integrating dropzone.js with laravel

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I'm trying to integrate dropzone.js with laravel 5 but I get empty FileBag when trying to dd($request).

In my view:

```
<form action="create-submit" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">...</form>
```

I included dropzone.css and basic.css, also I included dropzone.js in my HTML.

Route:

```
Route::get('content/create-submit', [
    'as' => 'create-submit', 'uses' => 'ContentController@createSubmit'
]);
```

Controller:

```
public function createSubmit (Request $request) {
    dd($request);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Is there an easy solution to integrate dropzone.js to laravel? Pls help

Comment: Not that familiar with dropzone but doesn't your `form` element need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and your route needs a `post` method, not `get`?

Comment: It has that part sorry I forgot to write it. edited

Comment: Are you using `POST` or `GET` to upload the image and form data? Since `GET` is limited to ~2000 characters, perhaps combined with all your other form data, something is being truncated?

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing dropzone in JS? It should do so automatically but sometimes it doesn't work as expect.

So I'm doing this.

```
<div class="dropzone" id="fileUpload" class="clear">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="true">
    var token = "{{ Session::getToken() }}";
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#fileUpload", {
        url: "{{ route('upload') }}",
        params: {
            _token: token
        }
    });
</script>
```

We are passing a CSRF token as part of the request in this case as well.

I'd suggest using web developer tools to see what response your getting when the upload is sent to the server.

UPDATE Controller code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        dd($file);
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution but no effect. How can I check if the file is actually uploaded? In the network part of the developer tools it says data:image/jpeg:base64... and data:image/png:base64... when I put some image on dropzone.

Comment: I've added a chunk of the code form my controller might help. If your seeing that in the network activity and getting a 200 OK as the response I'd expect it to be working.

Comment: It doesn't work. Dropzone shows progress bar OK as the file is uploaded and network activity as well. Then I click submit button on my form and it passes by if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) and continues.

Comment: As the $request doesn't have a file variable

Comment: This is what I get on network activity: UploadedFile {#31
  -test: false
  -originalName: "multimedija.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -size: 145446
  -error: 0
  path: "/tmp"...

Comment: Actually I have other stuff in a form like textboxes and I need to save those images in a database

Answer (score 0):

try manually initialize your dropzone like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", { 
                url: "/dropzone",
                headers: {
                   'x-csrf-token': document.querySelectorAll('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0].getAttributeNode('content').value,
                }
              });
});
```

and  in your controller

```
public function dropzone(Request $request)
    {
        $img    = $request->file('file'); //access dropzone files   
    }
```

Also, if no header token passed you will probably will not get any request.

For more detailed integration with laravel dropzone you can refer to this tutorial [Integrating Dropzone.js in Laravel 5 applications](http://anytch.com/integrating-dropzone-js-laravel-5-applications/)